# JavaScript for loop unwanted loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, parameter-passing

I am in the middle of making a blackjack program right now, and for some reason, when the user gets an extra card, it tells them the number of the extra card three times, when I just want the program to say that once, can someone help me out here? Thanks. (It asks the user if they want an extra card up to 3 times depending on their choice.)

```js
function cardNumber(a, b) {
  var cardTotal = a + b;
  alert(`Your card numbers are ${a} and ${b}!`);
  return cardTotal;
}

let cardRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var cardOne = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
var cardTwo = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
var cardSum = cardNumber(cardOne, cardTwo);

function moreCards(a, b) {
  alert(`Your extra card is ${b}!`);
  //outputs this three times? ^^^^
  var cardTotal = a + b;
  return cardTotal;
}

function inputValidation(cardSum) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3;) {
    var input = prompt(`Which makes your card total ${cardSum}. Would you like to draw another card? (Type in 1 for yes, 0 for no, or select cancel to return to home.)`);
    if (input === null) {
      window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
      //take this back to home.html ^^^
      i += 3;
    } else if (input === "1") {
      i++;
      var extraCard = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
      var cardSum = moreCards(cardSum, extraCard);
      moreCards(cardSum, extraCard);
    }
  }
}

inputValidation(cardSum);
```

Comment: You call `moreCards()` twice in the `else` block. What is the reason for the second one?

Comment: The first one is there to add the extra card to the card total, and the second one is there to output the moreCards() function.

Comment: Every time you cal the function it displays the message. You don't need to call it twice.

Comment: I only see the extra card twice, not 3 times.

Comment: Oh, it works fine now, thanks!